# Share a feeder among Gatling simulations

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using a CSV feeder to feed multiple simulations. When run using gatlingRun, every simulation starts reading the file from the beginning.
I am keeping the feeder in an object variable (must behave like a static variable):

```
object MyFeed  {
  val dataFile: String = Settings.dataFile

  val randomFeeder  = feed(tsv(dataFile))
}

object MySimulation extends Simulation{
    val myScenario: ChainBuilder =  MyFeed.randomFeeder
}
```

Is there a way to make all simulation use the same instance of the feeder or make each one continue where the others finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatling doesn't have any memory that survives between simulations. You'd have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for now by providing a separate data file and feeder for each simulation.

I hope someone finds a better solution or something changes in future releases!